# Absolute path with XML parser in java

Tags: java, xml, file, path

I have the following code to open up an XML file for parsing. My problem is with the variable `designPath`: it currently has to be a relative path from my program's root directory. However, when I pass an absolute path it doesn't work.

```
// Get the DOM Builder Factory
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

// Get the DOM Builder
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

// Load and Parse the XML document
// document contains the complete XML as a Tree
Document document = builder.parse(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(designPath));
```

How can I make this work with either an absolute or relative path in the `designPath` variable?

The issue is with the function `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream` that takes a "resource of the specified name from the search path used to load classes." according to Java docs but I want to be able to use it with an absolute path.

Note that my `designPath` may be on a different drive than my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in an `InputStream` instead:

```
// Get the DOM Builder Factory
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

// Get the DOM Builder
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

// Load and Parse the XML document
// document contains the complete XML as a Tree
File file = new File(PATH_TO_FILE);
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

Document document = builder.parse(inputStream);
```

or simple pass a new `File` object

```
// Get the DOM Builder Factory
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

// Get the DOM Builder
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

// Load and Parse the XML document
// document contains the complete XML as a Tree
Document document = builder.parse(new File(PATH_TO_FILE));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't because as you mentioned, getSystemResourceAsStream only searches the classpath.

You may have to so something like this.

```
Document document = null;
if (ClassLoader.getSystemResource(designPath) != null)
{
    document = builder.parse(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(designPath));
}
else
{
    // use standard file loader
    document = builder.parse(new File(designPath));
}
```

Swap the if clauses around if you want the file on the file system to take precedence.

Comment: What's the difference to passing in the `File` object straight away, as opposed to passing in the `InputStream` Object as in the above solution? Is there a difference?

Comment: If your classpath is something like CP=/home/user/xmlfiles:program.jar, and the file path is just design.xml, then your code will search /home/user/xmlfiles first, and if that fails, it will then look for design.xml relative to where you ran it.

Comment: @mohsaied I think in your case it doesn't matter whether you pass the InputStream or the File object, but in other cases you don't always get an InputStream from a file so it might make more sense to pass the InputStream. I'll update my answer so that others know there is an option!